# Save data along with headers My Sql python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

How to Save the csv file along with headers.

Below is the code which I am using but here I am getting only data not the headers part.

```
sql_data = "select * from ETSY_seller where Crawl_Date='2022-12-14' and Cohort = '418k'";
sql_cursor.execute(sql_data,multi=True)

data = sql_cursor.fetchall()

fp = open('/home/ec2-user/TV_eCommerce/US/extra/cohort418k_20221214.csv', 'w')

myFile = csv.writer(fp)

myFile.writerows(data)

fp.close()
```

Comment: Do you know the column names and can write them to the file first?  Or do you not know the column names and need to dynamically fetch them from the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the headers in the CSV file by modifying your code as follows:

```js
import csv
import mysql.connector

# establish database connection and cursor
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="your_host",
  user="your_username",
  password="your_password",
  database="your_database"
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

# execute SQL query to fetch data and headers
sql = "SELECT * FROM ETSY_seller WHERE Crawl_Date='2022-12-14' and Cohort = '418k'"
mycursor.execute(sql)
headers = [i[0] for i in mycursor.description]  # get column headers
data = mycursor.fetchall()

# write data and headers to CSV file
with open('/home/ec2-user/TV_eCommerce/US/extra/cohort418k_20221214.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(headers)
    writer.writerows(data)
```